# case-insensitive search of duplicate file-names

Tags: find, uniq, case-sensitivity, duplicate-files

I there a way to find all files in a directory with duplicate filenames, regardless of the casing (upper-case and/or lower-case)?

Answer (score 16):

If you have GNU utilities (or at least a set that can deal with zero-terminated lines) available, [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52952/2180) has a great method:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -z | uniq -diz
```

Note: the output will have zero-terminated strings; the tool you use to further process it should be able to handle that.

In the absence of tools that deal with zero-terminated lines, or if you want to make sure your code works in environments where such tools are not available, you need a small script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *; do
  find . -maxdepth 1 -iname ./"$f" -exec echo \; | wc -l | while read count; do
    [ $count -gt 1 ] && echo $f
  done
done
```

What is this madness?
See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23130/how-to-report-number-of-files-in-all-subdirectories/23139#23139) for an explanation of the techniques that make this safe for crazy filenames.

Comment: I was just going to post a similar... But worse answer :)

Comment: Do you really need the `-mindepth`'s?

Comment: I'm using Solaris.  Is /usr/bin/find the one you are talking about?
I tried using it and gave me many errors.

Comment: @lamcro No, Solaris doesn't use GNU's `find`; I've edited the answer to include a non-GNU solution.

Comment: Ok. Do I just paste it in a text file and give it execution rights?

Comment: @lamcro that should do it.

Comment: Typo `echo {} \;`

Comment: @Shawn J: +1.yes make sense.

Comment: @prince-john-wesley No, I only wanted the empty newline from `echo`. In fact, `echo {}` breaks it, since filenames can contain newlines, and that is what I'm counting in the next step.

-- I just changed it to `-printf "\n"` to be more straightforward.

Comment: Definitely the best method? `find . -maxdepth 1 | sort | uniq -di` is simpler and quicker.

Comment: @JamieKitson That will fail if you have filenames with newline characters.

Comment: Erm, edge case? :)

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff Well, if you've got GNU tools, `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -iz | uniq -diz` I added in some other options that are missing. Also, that'll leave you with NUL-terminated strings; if you want it readable, pipe to `tr '\0' '\n'` at the end (but, of course, then those LF files are a problem again)

Comment: This is an O(n²) solution to an O(n) or O(n log n) problem. As in my other comment, GNU sort and uniq can handle NUL-terminated items. That's O(n log n). (And yes, that should be -f to sort, not -i. Sorrry)

Comment: @derobert - that's definitely better - I've somehow blocked out that feature from my brain because it's just not available in the environment I usually use. Edited answer to include it.

Comment: Hey, you stole our answer! :)

Comment: @JamieKitson Say, what? Look again :-) I didn't know you had posted an answer other than the comment.

Comment: worked great too as `find |sort -f |uniq -di`

Answer (score 15):

There are many complicated answers above, this seems simpler and quicker than all of them:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | sort -f | uniq -di
```

If you want to find duplicate file names in subdirectories then you need to compare just the file name, not the whole path:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -printf "%f\n" | sort -f | uniq -di
```

Edit: Shawn J. Goff has pointed out that this will fail if you have filenames with newline characters. If you're using GNU utilities, you can make these work too:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -fz | uniq -diz
```

The `-print0` (for find) and `-z` option (for sort and uniq) cause them to work on NUL-terminated strings, instead of newline terminated strings. Since file names can not contain NUL, this works for all file names.

Comment: But see my comment on Shawn J. Goff's answer, you can add the -print0 option to find, and the -z option to uniq and sort. Also, you want -f on sort as well. Then it works. (I'm going to edit this into your answer, feel free to revert if you don't approve)

Comment: The last command is giving me output without carriage returns (result is all in one line). I'm using Red Hat Linux to run the command. The first command line works best for me.

Answer (score 3):

Sort the list of file names in a case-insensitive way and print duplicates. `sort` has an option for case-insensitive sorting. So does GNU `uniq`, but not other implementations, and all you can do with `uniq` is print every element in a set of duplicates except the first that's encountered. With GNU tools, assuming that no file name contains a newline, there's an easy way to print all the elements but one in each set of duplicates:

```
for x in *; do printf "%s\n" "$x"; done |
sort -f |
uniq -id
```

Portably, to print all elements in each set of duplicates, assuming that no file name contains a newline:

```
for x in *; do printf "%s\n" "$x"; done |
sort -f |
awk '
    tolower($0) == tolower(prev) {
        print prev;
        while (tolower($0) == tolower(prev)) {print; getline}
    }
    1 { prev = $0 }'
```

If you need to accommodate file names containing newlines, go for Perl or Python. Note that you may need to tweak the output, or better do your further processing in the same language, as the sample code below uses newlines to separate names in its own output.

```
perl -e '
    foreach (glob("*")) {push @{$f{lc($_)}}, $_}
    foreach (keys %f) {@names = @{$f{$_}}; if (@names > 1) {print "$_\n" foreach @names}}
'
```

Here's a pure zsh solution. It's a bit verbose, as there's no built-in way to keep the duplicate elements in an array or glob result.

```
a=(*)(N); a=("${(@io)a}")
[[ $#a -le 1 ]] ||
for i in {2..$#a}; do
  if [[ ${(L)a[$i]} == ${(L)a[$((i-1))]} ]]; then
    [[ ${(L)a[$i-2]} == ${(L)a[$((i-1))]} ]] || print -r $a[$((i-1))]
    print -r $a[$i]
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed it this way:

```
find . | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -d
```

I used `find` instead of `ls` cause I needed the full path (a lot of subdirectories) included.  I did not find how to do this with `ls`.

Comment: Both `sort` and `uniq` have ignore-case flags, f and i respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Without GNU `find`:

`LANG=en_US ls | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | uniq -c | awk '$1 >= 2 {print $2}'`

Comment: `tr` is *very* likely to wreak havoc on any character set which uses more than a single byte per character. Only the first 256 characters of UTF-8 are safe when using `tr`.   
  From [Wikipedia tr (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29)..  
  *Most versions of `tr`, including GNU `tr` and classic Unix `tr`,  
   operate on SINGLE BYTES and are not Unicode compliant..*

Comment: Update to my previous comment.. only the first **128** characters of UTF-8 are safe. All UTF-8 characters above the ordinal range  **0..127** are all multi-byte and can  have individual byte values in other characters. Only the bytes in the range **0..127**  have a one-to-one association to a unique character.

Comment: Plus `uniq` has a case-insensitive flag i.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Question:

> I there a way to find all files in a directory with duplicate filenames, regardless of the casing (upper-case and/or lower-case)?

#### An Answer:

I found this works for me on Ubuntu 20.04. I tested this in my home directory with a *contrived* duplication of filenames; i.e.:

```bsh
$ touch filename.txt
$ touch FiLeNaMe.TxT
```

And then:

```bsh
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -f | uniq -Di 
./filename.txt
./FiLeNaMe.TxT
```

- `find .` : search begins in `pwd` - `~/` in this case
- `-maxdepth 1` : `find` defaults to full recursion; this limits that to `pwd` only
- `-type -f` : "regular" files only - no directories, links, etc
- `sort -f` : sort required as `uniq` requires **adjacency**; `-f` ignores *case*
- `uniq -Di` : `-D` prints all dupes; `-i` ignores case

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly lamcro wanted to be certain of finding every one of a suspected small number of such duplicates.  I have found that using FileZilla to do a file transfer of an entire directory to a Windows-based file system causes each and every instance to be caught with a dialog which asks what action to take.  Each dialog contains enough information to be certain where the duplicates are, though admittedly it is clumsy compared with a true search, which would generate a list.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else who wants to then rename etc one of the files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | sort -f | uniq -di | while read f; do echo mv "$f" "${f/.txt/_.txt}"; done
```