# Use of ls with wc command

Tags: ls, wc

What does the command :

```
ls | wc -l
```

do? I know

```
wc <filename>
```

gives lines, words, and characters, and

```
wc -l <filename>
```

print the line count. But how it is being used with ls` is not clear. What does it do?

Answer (score 7):

*On first glance*, it counts the number of files in a directory (`ls` lists files, `wc -l` counts them).

**But wait**. Try this:

```
> mkdir test
> touch test/magic$'\n'newlines
> ls test | wc -l
2
```

[Turns out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23163/newlines-in-filenames) the POSIX standard allows newlines in filenames. Because of this and other edge cases, the general method for counting the number of files in a directory is [a lot more complicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23130/how-to-report-number-of-files-in-all-subdirectories?lq=1).

There was once talk of adding a `--zero` flag to `ls` to allow such monstrosities to be split (the null character is illegal in POSIX filenames), but it never materialised [due to resistance from the `coreutils` devs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112125/is-there-a-reason-why-ls-does-not-have-a-zero-or-0-option/112128?noredirect=1#comment173854_112128).

Doing `ls | wc -l` is probably safe for a casual check, but don't rely on it when you need standards-compliant code.

Comment: Uch. +1 because you are entirely correct, but this ridiculous situation of allowing newlines in filenames is just... *ugh*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pipe `|` between two commands. Namely, `ls` which lists the contents of a  directory and `wc` which will count the number of lines output from the `ls` command. (The pipe joins the output from first command to input of second, and so forth).

So the result is the number of files/directories found in this directory.

Comment: ls does a list without line jump so the command will not count the number of file and should return always 1, `ls | wc -w` should count the number of file (and it can't be used if space in filename) so the only goog stuff to use is `ls -l | wc -l`

Comment: @Kiwy most modern versions of `ls` automatically go to 'one file per line'-mode when the output is a pipe rather than an interactive terminal.

Comment: OK I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` lists files in a directory, and the command `wc` (aka. word count) returns the occurrences of lines in this example.

These commands can take a variety of switches (the `-l` after `wc` is called a switch). So you could have `wc` count the number of words or characters too.

#### Example

```
$ mkdir tst
$ cd tst
$ touch {1..5}
$ ls | wc -l
5

$ ls |wc
      5       5      10
```

**NOTE:** So here we have 5 "newlines", 5 words, and 10 characters. The 10 characters are the 1,2,3,4,5 and the corresponding `\n` (aka. newline character) that occurs after them in the output.

*excerpt* from the `wc` man page:

> Print newline, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total line if more than one FILE is specified.  With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

So in our above examples we're using the "read standard input" which means take the input from the output of the `ls` command via the pipe (`|`). This is how in Unix you can chain commands together to do complicated things with very "basic" command line tools.