# Recursively rename e-mail files from .txt to .eml

Tags: find, rename

Directory "$d" contains a few thousand e-mail files with the .txt extension. To open them in my e-mail client, I need to rename them to .eml

Will this command rename them correctly:

```
find "${d}" -type f -name '*.txt' | while read f; do mv -vn "${f}" "${f%.*}".eml; done
```

or is there a better, more robust way to do this?

I could not think of an elegant way of doing this using:

```
-exec ...{}... \;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is generally ok, but it will break on newlines. Here is a slightly more robust bash4+ solution:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in **/*.txt; do
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}.eml"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine with

```
find "$d" -name \*.txt -exec rename .txt .eml {} \;
```

or even

```
for f in *.txt; do rename .txt .eml "$f"; done
```

if all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: The system I am on does not have "rename".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your command will work, assuming you're using `bash` or a shell with similar syntax.  In the future when you're contemplating a big command like this, remember that you can use `echo` to preview the resulting command lines.  I.e. you could put `echo` in front of `mv`, run the pipeline and see what the commands are going to be.  If they look OK, remove `echo` and run the command for real.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh, [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) makes this easy. Put `autoload -U zmv` in your `~/.zshrc`, then use one of several ways of specifying a replacement text for `**/*.txt` which matches files with the extension `txt` in the current directory and subdirectories:

```
zmv '**/*.txt' '$f:r.eml'
zmv '**/*.txt' '${f%.*}.eml'
zmv '(**/)(*).txt' '$1$2.eml'
zmv -w '**/*.txt' '$1$2.eml'
```

If you don't have zsh, but you have bash ≥4 or ksh93, you can use the `**` to traverse subdirectories recursively and then loop over the matches. You'll need to activate the `**` glob pattern first with `shopt -s globstar` in bash (put it in your `~/.bashrc`) or `set -o globstar` in ksh (put it in your `~/.kshrc`). This also works in zsh (no prior setup needed).

```
for f in **/*.txt; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.eml"; done
```

Note that this renames all files, not just regular files. If you have directories or other non-regular files and you want to leave them untouched:

```
zmv -Q '**/*.txt(.)' '$f:r.eml'
for f in **/*.txt; do [[ -f $f ]] && mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}.eml"; done
```

With no shell feature beyond POSIX, you'll need to invoke `find` to traverse subdirectories. Your solution is brittle because it breaks on files containing backslashes, trailing whitespace or newlines. You can fix the trailing whitespace and backslashes issue with [`while IFS= read -r f; do …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs) but piping the output of `find` inherently breaks on newlines. Use `-exec` instead. On Linux, you can use the `rename` utility ([whichever your distribution carries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78621/find-rename-command-doesnt-work/78645#78645)). On Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives:

```
rename 's/\.txt$/.eml/' **/*.txt
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec rename 's/\.txt$/.eml/' {} +
```

On other distributions, as long as none of the file names contain `.txt` in the middle (because `rename` substitutes the first occurence of the source string):

```
rename .txt .eml **/*.txt
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec rename .txt .eml {} +
```

With only POSIX features throughout, invoke a shell to perform the transformation on the name.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}.eml"; done' _ {} +
```

If your `find` is too old to support `-exec … +`, you'll need to invoke one shell per file, which makes for simpler but slower code.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.*}.eml"; done' {} \;
```