# find/rename command doesn't work

Tags: find, rename

I am using Linux Slackware 14.0, bash 4.2. Suppose, I have 2 files in the directory:

```
bash-4.2$ ls
1.txt  2.txt
```

I want to rename them to .svg. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/213134/recursively-rename-files-change-extension-in-linux) is accepted and upvoted, so I think, it must work. He used this command:

```
find . -name "*.andnav" -exec rename -v 's/\.andnav$/\.tile/i' {} \;
```

So, I wrote the analogous command, but it printed an error:

```
bash-4.2$ find . -name "*.txt" -exec rename -v 's/\.txt$/\.svg/i' {} \;
rename: not enough arguments
```

When I want to just print the files, it works:

```
bash-4.2$ find . -name "*.txt" -print
./1.txt
./2.txt
```

I know, that I can rename with a simpler approach:

```
bash-4.2$ rename .txt .svg ./*.txt
bash-4.2$ ls
1.svg  2.svg
```

But why doesn't the command from *that* answer work for me?

Comment: There are two completely different rename implementation on Linux: the one from `perl` (which that answer assumes) and the one from util-linux (which you have).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas How to convert that answer to use my implementation?

Comment: `find . -name '*.txt' -exec rename .txt .svg {} +`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Worked, thx. Where can I read the docs, explaining the syntax you used: '{} +'?

Comment: `info --index-search=-exec find`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two commands called `rename` on Linux distributions. There is [one in the basic Linux utilities](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rename.ul), which is used like this:

```
rename SUBSTRING REPLACEMENT FILE...
```

This command replaces the first occurrence of SUBSTRING by REPLACEMENT in each of the specified files. It only supports plain strings, not wildcards or regexps. On Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, etc.), this command is called `rename.ul`. On other Linux distributions, it's called `rename`.

There is also a [perl script called `rename`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rename) which is used like this:

```
rename 'PERL CODE' FILE...
```

A common form of Perl code is `rename 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/' FILE...`, which replaces the first occurrence of REGEXP by REPLACEMENT in each file name (`s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/g` replaces all occurrences).

The author of [the question you saw](https://superuser.com/questions/213134/recursively-rename-files-change-extension-in-linux) indicated that he's running Ubuntu, hence he accepted [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/213134/recursively-rename-files-change-extension-in-linux/213146#213146) using the `rename` command found on Ubuntu.

The analog for the standard `rename` command is

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec rename .txt .svg {} \;
```

With bash ≥4, you can use the [`**` wildcard pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) after setting the [`globstar` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) to match files in subdirectories without using `find`.

```
shopt -s globstar
rename .txt .svg **/*.txt
```

Beware that this `rename` command acts on the first string, so if you have a file called `hello.txt.world.txt`, it'll be renamed to `hello.svg.world.txt`.