# How to drop some string in every filename

Tags: filenames, rename

`[root@localhost ~]# ls *.bak`

> `test2.bak  test3.bak  test9.bak  test.bak  test.txt.bak`

How to drop all `.bak` in all file?This is my current try

`ls *.bak|xargs -t -i mv {}.bak {}`

But it don't work for me.Is there any workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`rename`** command:

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

---

- `'s/\.bak$//'` - *perl* expression to match all filenames ending with `.bak` and strip the extension

Comment: I don't know why it [don't work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tnhIb.png) for me.

Comment: @yode, try `prename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak` (Perl version)

Comment: It's seem `rename .bak '' *.bak` work for this..

Comment: it seems that you are using another implementation, see this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78621/find-rename-command-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

A loop should do (in a POSIX-like shell):

```
for f in *.bak; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

And as one line:

```
for f in *.bak; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that should work across all platforms:

```
for i in *.bak
do
  mv $i `echo $i | sed 's/\.bak$//'`
done
```

Comment: You need quotes around `$i` and the command substitution to deal with whitespace in filenames. (Some newlines would still cause somewhat odd results.)

Answer (score 0):

As the promp of [RomanPerekhrest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/148009/romanperekhrest)'s answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372973/237289),I find this command work for me.

```
rename .bak '' *.bak
```

Comment: Note that it would rename `best.baker.bak` to `bester.bak` and would choke on file names that start with `-`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for val in \`ls *.bat`
do
    mv $val `echo $val | cut -f1 -d'.'`
done
```

Comment: That makes a lot of assumptions, like that none of the bat files are of type _directory_, that their names don't contain space, tab, newline, `*`, `?`, `[` backslash characters, that they don't start with `-`, that they contain no other `.` characters.

Comment: The `ls` here doesn't do anything (but cause issues), the shell still generates the list of file names. See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29