# Rename all the files with a specific extension in all the subdirectory

Tags: find, rename, recursive

I have a lot of directories. Each one of these has a file with a specific extension `.ext`.

I want to rename these files.

Example:

```
// Note: The names are random, can have spaces and special characters

Parent
 |
 |- First Directory
 |   |
 |   |- Some file.txt
 |   |- Another one.pdf
 |   `- The one to rename.ext
 |
 |- Second Directory
 |   |
 |   |- Some file.txt
 |   |- Another one.pdf
 |   `- The one to rename.ext
[…]
```

I want to rename all the file with the `.ext` extension to `new name.ext2`. There is only one file with the `.ext` per directory, so no problem with that.

What I have done so far is:

```
find ./Parent -name "*.ext" -exec mv "{}" "{}.ext2" \;
```

And I get a bunch of `The one to rename.ext.ext2`, I am stuck about renaming them `new name.ext2`. If I just set it as the second argument of `mv`, it will move them into the `Parent` directory, and thus, each call to the `mv`function will overwrite the previous moved file.

Note: I couldn't make it work using the `-exec bash -c ''` argument. I tried something along the lines of:

```
find ./Parent -name "*.ext" -exec bash -c 'mv {} "$(dirname {})/new name.ext2"' \;
```

But I get some issue with the `$()` being expanded before `{}`

Comment: Also [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40539/recursively-rename-e-mail-files-from-txt-to-eml), which is a more similar question but with answers less applicable to what you're trying.

Comment: I already searched on Google and the SE sites; I am asking because I still couldn't make it work after reading them. :-)

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40545/73093) does *exactly* what you asked.

Comment: If that specific part is your problem, the second candidate dupe is a better pairing (but all the answers are quite different approaches to what you've been trying and it doesn't match the title question as well).

Comment: @MichaelHomer: Unfortunately, not all systems can call the `shopt -s globstar nullglob` command. (c.f. [comment on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470258/how-do-i-find-all-files-with-the-same-name-in-all-subdirectories)) It doesn't work on OSX and I can't upgrade bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-printf` function of `find` to construct your commands:

```
find /tmp -name "*.ext" -printf "mv %p %h/new_name.ext"
mv /tmp/foo.ext /tmp/new_name.ext
```

When you surround the command with `$()`, the commands will be executed:

```
$(find /tmp -name "*.ext" -printf "mv %p %h/new_name.ext")
find /tmp -name "*.ext"
/tmp/new_name.ext
```

**Update:**

The above command does not correctly work on multiple files and did not use quotes values. Use the below command instead:

```
find /tmp -name \*.ext\*
/tmp/dir with space/bar.ext
/tmp/foo.ext

bash -x < <(find /tmp -name "*.ext" -printf "mv \"%p\" \"%h/new_name.ext2\"\n")
+ mv '/tmp/dir with space/bar.ext' '/tmp/dir with space/new_name.ext2'
+ mv /tmp/foo.ext /tmp/new_name.ext2

find /tmp -name \*.ext\*
/tmp/dir with space/new_name.ext2
/tmp/new_name.ext2
```

Comment: After you change `new_name.ext` to `new name.ext2` (what the question asks for), this will output `mv Parent/First Directory/The one to rename.ext Parent/First Directory/new name.ext2` — without any quotes.  How well do you suppose that's going to work as a command?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`

```
for file in */*.ext; do
    ext2=`echo $file | sed 's/.ext/.ext2/'`
    mv $file $ext2
done
```

Comment: (1) For clarity, you might want to change `\`…\`` to `$(…)` — see [this](/q/5778/80216), [this](/q/147838/80216), and [this](/q/104119/80216).  (2) You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$file"` and `"$ext2"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  (3) This renames `The one to rename.ext` to `The one to rename.ext2` — but the question calls for it to be renamed to `new name.ext2`.  (4) A safer `sed` command would be `s/\.ext$/.ext2/`.  The one you are using would change `mytextfile.ext` to `my.ext2file.ext`.