# IFS null is not the same as unset IFS?

Tags: shell, shell-script, bourne-shell

I read a great question on here called [Understanding IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs). I was surprised because the answers and comments quote POSIX which states that IFS= is not the same as unsetting IFS. If you unset IFS, apparently the default value is used. If you make IFS null instead, there is no splitter. I knew I had seen a different take on that, and I found this in my bookmarks:

[Bourne Shell Programming](http://www.ooblick.com/text/sh/)

> $IFS
>
> The very first statement in your script should be
>
> IFS=
>
> which resets the input field separator to its default value.
>   Otherwise, you inherit $IFS from the user, who may have set it to some
>   bizarre value in order to make sh parse strings differently from the
>   way you expect, and induce weird behavior.

So was that true some time ago or is the author just wrong?

Answer (score 22):

The answers you found on Stack Exchange are right and this tutorial is wrong. You can experiment by yourself or look it up in the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05). An unset `IFS` is equivalent to setting it to the default value of space-tab-newline, while an empty `IFS` effectively turns off field splitting.

You can consult [Sven Mascheck's page on IFS](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ifs/) about historical implementations. A few historical shells didn't like `unset IFS`, and a very old version of ksh treated it like an empty `IFS` but all modern shells and most old shells treat an unset `IFS` like the default value.

You should not start your script with `IFS=` unless you want to turn off field splitting (which can be a reasonable decision — but note that you still need to put double quotes around substitutions to avoid globbing, unless you turn that off with `set -f` too). To reset the default value, use `unset IFS`. It's debatable whether this is useful at the beginning of a script; there are plenty of other bad things such as a dodgy `PATH` that the caller can do to make your script go wrong.

This tutorial also advises to reset `PATH`. This is usually bad advice. In most cases, you cannot predict what the correct search path is, but the user knows. How do you know whether `/usr/local/bin` or `/home/bob/bin` contains bug-fixed versions of utilities on an ancient unix where the ones in `/usr/bin` are buggy? Do you really want to embed all the logic to figure out whether to put `/usr/xpg6/bin` ahead of `/bin`? At what position you want `/usr/gnu/bin`? Do not reset PATH unless your script targets a specific system.

I haven't read this tutorial, but I did check one thing: it doesn't tell you right from the start to always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions. So I do not think this tutorial is a good one.

Comment: `unset IFS` does not reset IFS to its default value in bash though it does reset field-splitting.

Comment: @Melab `unset IFS` does not reset `IFS` to its default value, it unsets it. But an unset `IFS` has the same effect as `IFS` set to the default value.