# why do we not need export here?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

```
$ IFS=";"

$ read first second 
i am;a_i b c
$ echo $first
i am
$ echo $second
a_i b c

$ echo $IFS
```

1. Am I right that `read first second` is a subprocess of the current
   shell process? If yes, why don't we need `export IFS=";"`?
2. why is `IFS` empty?

Comment: What shell are you using? `a=";"; echo $a` produces `;`. Tested using bash on Debian Gnu+Linux.

Comment: Strangely it needs quotes for `IFS` but not `a`: `IFS=";"; echo $IFS` produces blank line, but `IFS=";"; echo "$IFS"` produces `;`.

Comment: And now it is broken for `a` as well. so it type `IFS=" "`, and now it is working for `a` without the quotes. Therefore the value of `IFS` is changing the behaviour.

Comment: bash. @richard .

Answer (score 5):

> Am I right that read first second is a subprocess of the current shell
>   process? If yes, why don't we need export IFS=";"?

No, `read` is a [bash bultin function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). No subshell or subprocess is created here, so we don't need to export `IFS`.

> why is IFS empty?

Because you don't use double quote. You have changed value IFS to `;`, so when you `echo $IFS`, after `$IFS` is expanded to `;`, the shell performs word spliting and globbing, with `;` as separator. So nothing is printed.

Try:

```
$ IFS=";"
$ printf "%s\n" $IFS

$ printf "%s\n" "$IFS"
;
```

**Note**

- [Understanding IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs)

Comment: Thanks. (1) if `read` is not a builtin, will I have to `export IFS=";"`? (2) why do I need double quote for `$IFS`? Why can i `echo $a`, if replacing `IFS` with `a`?

Comment: @Tim: (1) Yes. (2) Because you have changed value `IFS` to `;`, so when you `echo $IFS`, after `$IFS` is expanded to `;`, the shell performs spliting fields and globbing, with `;` as separator. So nothing is printed.

Comment: The answers at that link are not very good.

Comment: Depending on the shell, `echo $IFS` will output NL (where $IFS is a field delimiter (bash, some implementations/versions of ksh or dash) or non-whitespace are not considered different from whitespace (Bourne)) as it's like `echo ''`. And with others (where `$IFS` is a field separator (zsh, yash, some versions/implementations of dash or ksh), it will output SPC NL as it's like `echo ''  ''`

Answer (score 1):

If we type `type read` we get `read is a shell builtin`. Therefore it is not run as a sub-process.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to why IFS is empty. It is not. But the value in `IFS` is changing the behaviour of the shell. Below is not an explanation but just the result of my experiments using bash on Debian Gnu+Linux.

`a=";"; echo $a` produces `;`.

`IFS=";"; echo $IFS` produces blank line.
`IFS=";"; echo "$IFS"` produces `;`.

Now `a=";"; echo $a` produces blank line, but `IFS=" "; a=";"; echo $a` produces `;` again.

So

Now `IFS=";"; a=";"; echo $a` produces blank line, but `IFS=" "; a=";"; echo $a` produces `;`.

Therefore the value of IFS changes the behaviour (then quotes not used in echo).

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=\;; set -- $IFS; echo $#; echo "$*"

1
;

IFS=; set -- $IFS; echo $#; echo "$*"

0
#there doesn't seem to be anything here
```

As you can see - `$IFS` is not empty in the first case - it contains exactly one field separator.

When the shell expands an unquoted variable it splits its value on the delimiters defined in `$IFS`. In this way each variable is, potentially, an `$IFS` separated array. By default `$IFS` is set to a `<space>`, a `\t`ab, and a `\n`ewline. Each of these has special qualities in `$IFS` as they are *`$IFS` whitespace*.  *`$IFS` whitespace* delimiters are not retained and each sequence of either is instead truncated to a single field when the shell performs the wordsplitting, whereas all others will delimit a single field per separator. *`$IFS` whitespace* will also be removed entirely from either the beginning or end of a field. For instance:

```
IFS=/; slashes=///////; printf '<%s>' $slashes
<><><><><><><>

IFS=' '; spaces='      '; printf '<%s>' $spaces
<>

printf '<%s>' $spaces$slashes
<///////>
```

But *`$IFS` whitespace* is obviously *not* removed when it is *not* in `$IFS`:

```
IFS=/; printf '<%s>' $spaces$slashes
<      ><><><><><><>
```