# Why is $COLUMNS not listed by either env or set? (on zsh)

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, env

I can

```
$ echo $COLUMNS
95
```

and get a result, but if I

```
env | grep COLUMNS
```

or

```
set | grep COLUMNS
```

I get nothing.

(Update: I just discovered that the behavior is different on bash.  I'm using zsh.)

Secondarily, how/where can I get a listing that includes COLUMNS.  (Not including just echoing it directly.)

Comment: On `zsh`, `set` does contain `COLUMNS` for me. I can't grep it directly, since IFS apparently contains a `\0`, so `grep` treats it as binary (I have to use `--text`).

Comment: `zsh --version` gives me `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)`.  I quadruple checked, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: I'm on Linux (`zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`). Can you manually inspect the output of `set` (using `less`, for example)?

Comment: aha: `set | grep --text COLUMNS` gives it to me.  If you post an answer with as much explanation as you can (or as is reasonable, if you could write volumes), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to guess, I'd suspect [`IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs). `set` lists `IFS` too. And for me, `IFS` is (space, horizontal tab, newline and nul):

```
$ printf "%s" "$IFS" | od -a
0000000  sp  ht  nl nul
0000004
```

The presence of the NUL character (`\0`) causes `grep` to treat it as a binary file, so depending on your `grep`, you may see:

```
$ set | grep COLUMNS        
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

You can force `grep` to treat the input as text:

```
-a, --text
    Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent 
    to the --binary-files=text option.
```

And so:

```
$ set | grep COLUMNS --text
COLUMNS=239
```

Answer (score 4):

`set | grep COLUMNS` should display “Binary file (standard input) matches” (with GNU grep). [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172608) has correctly identified the culprit: under zsh, `IFS` contains the null byte in addition to the standard characters space, tab, newline.

Run `set | grep --text COLUMNS` to make grep ignore its inclination to skip binary files.

Running `set` is not a portable, reliable way to list currently-set parameters, because its output is ambiguous in many shells (you can't distinguish a newline that's part of a variable value from the newline that separates variables). The output of `set` in zsh happens to be quoted so as to be unambiguous, but it's hard to parse: `grep` could still return false positives. To list all the parameters in zsh, enumerate the keys of the `parameters` array:

```
print -rl ${(ko)parameters}
```