# What is the meaning of IFS=$'\n' in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

At the beginning of a bash shell script is the following line:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

What is the meaning behind this collection of symbols?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs and the questions it cites.

Comment: vim syntax highlights this as an error for me; fix?

Comment: `IFS=$'\n'` is a bashism (+ other shells, use [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), for workarounds see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748703/iterate-over-lines-instead-of-words-in-a-for-loop-of-shell-script/10752407

Answer (score 335):

`IFS` stands for "internal field separator". It is used by the shell to determine how to do word splitting, i. e. how to recognize word boundaries.

Try this in a shell like bash (other shells may handle this differently, for example zsh):

```
mystring="foo:bar baz rab"
for word in $mystring; do
  echo "Word: $word"
done
```

The default value for `IFS` consists of whitespace characters (to be precise: space, tab and newline). Each character can be a word boundary. So, with the default value of `IFS`, the loop above will print:

```
Word: foo:bar
Word: baz
Word: rab
```

In other words, the shell thinks that whitespace is a word boundary.

Now, try setting `IFS=:` before executing the loop. This time, the result is:

```
Word: foo
Word: bar baz rab
```

Now, the shell splits `mystring` into words as well -- but now, it only treats a colon as the word boundary.

The first character of `IFS` is special: It is used to delimit words in the output when using the special `$*` variable (example taken from the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html), where you can also find more information on special variables like that one):

```
$ bash -c 'set w x y z; IFS=":-;"; echo "$*"'
w:x:y:z
```

Compare to:

```
$ bash -c 'set w x y z; IFS="-:;"; echo "$*"'
w-x-y-z
```

Note that in both examples, the shell will still treat all of the characters `:`, `-` and `;` as word boundaries. The only thing that changes is the behaviour of `$*`.

Another important thing to know is how so-called "IFS whitespace" [is treated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05). Basically, as soon as `IFS` includes whitespace characters, leading and trailing whitespace is stripped from the string to be split before processing it and a **sequence** of consecutive whitespace characters delimits fields as well. However, this only applies to those whitespace characters which are actually present in `IFS`.

For example, let's look at the string `"a:b:: c  d "` (trailing space and two space characters between `c` and `d`).

1. With `IFS=:` it would be split into four fields: `"a"`, `"b"`, `""` (empty string) and `" c  d "` (again, two spaces between `c` and `d`). Note the leading and trailing whitespace in the last field.
2. With `IFS=' :'`, it would be split into five fields: `"a"`, `"b"`, `""` (empty string), `"c"` and `"d"`. No leading and trailing whitespace anywhere.

Note how multiple, consecutive whitespace characters delimit two fields in the second example, while multiple, consecutive colons don't (since they are not whitespace characters).

As for `IFS=$'\n'`, that is a `ksh93` syntax also supported by `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh` and FreeBSD `sh` (with variations between all shells). Quoting the bash manpage:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to "string", with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

`\n` is the escape sequence for a newline, so `IFS` ends up being set to a single newline character.

Comment: This is good, but, in my opinion, you'd do a lot better to read and understand the POSIX spec rather than the `bash` scripting guide, or whatever. In the main, the information available at links like that is lacking in important ways. Anyway, thus misses two crucial points concerning shell splitting - globbing and IFS whitespace.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks, I added some information on IFS whitespace. Didn't know about that. :)

Comment: Not as relevant, but if you're curious, you might want to look at how `unset IFS` makes a shell behave very differently than `IFS=`. Also the first byte in IFS is special to `"${named_array[*]}"` as well - but neither matters when the expansion is unquoted..

Comment: A few more points: 1- word splitting, governed by `$IFS` is one of the two main things performed upon expanding an unquoted variable in list context (it's the `split` part of the `split+glob` operator). The other one is globbing. When using work splitting, you generally need to issue `set -f` to disable the `glob` part.

Comment: 2- `$IFS` and the `split+glob` operator is used on unquoted parameter expansion (`$var`, `$#`...) but also for unquoted command substitution (`\`...\`` and `$(...)`) and unquoted arithmetic expansion (`$((...))` or `$[...]` in some shells).

Comment: 3- `$IFS` is also used by the `read` builtin command

Comment: 4- While `$IFS` was the internal field separator initially in the Bourne shell, in POSIX shells, it's rather the _internal field delimiter_ as in `a:b:` with `IFS=:` is split into `a` and `b` only (not `a`, `b` and the empty string).

Comment: What's the purpose of the oddball `IFS=$'\n'` versus the more familiar `IFS="\n"` or `IFS="\x0A"`? The shell auto-escapes double-quoted strings by default.

Comment: @Beejor: The `$''` syntax expands the `\n`, so it breaks on an actual newline instead of `\ ` and `n`.

Comment: +1 for the double quotes question, I also don't understand how `$'\n'` is different from `"\n"`, if both expand the `\n` to a newline`? which one should I use for better portability?

Comment: @szx `"\n"` (or`'\n'`) is not the same as `$'\n'`. The first string consists of the characters _backslash_ and `n`. `$'\n'` results in a single newline character. For best portability, you cannot use `$'\n'` since it's only supported by certain shells. One hacky way to set IFS to a newline character would be `IFS=$(printf '\n.'); IFS=${IFS%.}` (command expansion removes trailing newlines, so we add and then remove another trailing character to work around that).

Answer (score 38):

Inside dollared single quotes, some characters are evaluated specially. For example, `\n` is translated to new line.

So, this particular line assigns newline to the variable IFS. IFS, in turn, is a special variable in bash: Internal Field Separator. As `man bash` says, it

> is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the `read` builtin command.  The default value is `<space><tab><newline>`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `dollared single quotes` which is different from simple single quotes.

Comment: @Snowcrash +1 for saying *+1 for mentioning of **dollared single quotes** which is different from simple single quotes*. Sorry, couldn't help it :) But actually it's a really good thing to point out because it is important!

Comment: @Pryftan +1 for +1 for +1... you know... it's really important.

Comment: @0xc0de Definitely agree! Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 28):

For short, `IFS=$'\n'` assign newline `\n` to variable `IFS`.

`$'string'` construct is a quoting mechanism which use to decode ANSI C like escape sequences. This syntax comes from `ksh93`, and was portable to modern shell like `bash`, `zsh`, `pdksh`, `busybox sh`.

This syntax is not defined by POSIX, but was accepted for [SUS issue 7](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249#c590).

Answer (score 2):

I prefered to explain `$IFS` via example:
Suppsoe you want to cp or mv or another file proccessing, IFS is empty by defualt, When your files have meta char or space such as :

`Linux Administration.pdf` or `Free Software Fundation.ogg` , Sure you'll have probelm, Because :
Linux consider a seperate param and Administartion consider a seperate param.So bash has `built-in variable` , Then you can initialize to `IFS==$(echo -en "\n\b")` , Then bash discard any meta char and space between file name, For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
mymusicdir=~/test/dd
find $mymusicdir -name "*" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" +
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```