# Bash: Iterating 2 lists using single For In loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have 2 seperate loops

```
for file1 in `ls Dir1/` ; do
    echo $file1
done

for file2 in `ls Dir2/` ; do
    echo $file2
done
```

I want Single loop to iterate both Directories
pseudocode

```
for file1 , file2 in `ls Dir1` , `ls Dir2`
do
    echo $file1
    echo file2
done
```

Is it possible

Comment: you cant do that, but you could use a function that takes the dir as a parameter and iterates through its files.

Comment: if you explain what actually you are trying to do, instead of a code which does nothing significant, may be you can get a different suggestion than looping through two directories in a single for loop. Just a thought.

Comment: I want to iterate files of 2 directories 1 by 1

Comment: dir1 has many files
dir2 has many files
I want to work on file1 from dir1 and file1 from dir2 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `while` loop with suitable input can do the job, assuming no newline characters in the file names.

```
paste -d/ <(ls /var) <(ls /usr) |
  while IFS=/ read -r e u; do
    printf '%s\n' "$e $u"
  done
```

Comment: Thank you
Can you tell me what is IFS-thwarting characters
or you can give me link

Comment: I got it what is meant by IFS
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting

Answer (score 2):

You generally [don't want to parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Here, with `zsh` (you're already using `zsh` syntax, not `bash` as you're not quoting your variables and using command substitution without disabling globbing), you could do:

```
dir1_file_names=(dir1/*(N:t))
dir2_file_names=(dir2/*(N:t))
for f1 f2 (${dir1_file_names:^dir2_file_names})
  printf '%s\n' "f1: $f1, f2: $f2"
```

`zsh` can loop with several variables. `${a:^b}` is an *array zipping* operator. If one of the arrays have fewer elements than the other, it will be as if they were truncated to the length of the smallest.

See also its array intersection and subtraction operators if it's about comparing the file names in the two directories:

```
file_names_in_both_dir1_and_dir2=(${dir1_file_names:*dir2_file_names})
file_names_only_in_dir1=(${dir1_file_name:|dir2_file_names})
file_names_only_in_dir2=(${dir2_file_name:|dir1_file_names})
```

Comment: Sometimes using `zsh` almost feels like cheating

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt -s nullglob

dir1names=( Dir1/* )
dir2names=( Dir2/* )

while [ "${#dir1names[@]}" -gt 0 ] &&
      [ "${#dir2names[@]}" -gt 0 ]
do

    printf '%s\n' "${dir1names[0]##*/}"
    printf '%s\n' "${dir2names[0]##*/}"

    dir1names=( "${dir1names[@]:1}" )
    dir2names=( "${dir2names[@]:1}" )
done
```

This uses `bash` to get all the pathnames from each directory into two arrays.  It then prints the filename portion of these pathnames (like `ls` would do), alternating between the arrays, and deletes the printed entires from the arrays.  It stops when one of the arrays is completely empty.

The `nullglob` shell option makes non-matched globbing patterns expand to nothing rather than remain unexpanded.

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- Dir1
|   |-- file-1
|   |-- file-2
|   |-- file-3
|   `-- file-4
|-- Dir2
|   |-- otherfile-1
|   |-- otherfile-2
|   |-- otherfile-3
|   |-- otherfile-4
|   |-- otherfile-5
|   `-- otherfile-6
`-- script.sh

2 directories, 11 files
```

```
$ bash script.sh
file-1
otherfile-1
file-2
otherfile-2
file-3
otherfile-3
file-4
otherfile-4
```

---

If this is *actually* about pairing up files according to their names, so that a file in one directory are paired with the corresponding  file in another (as is sometimes done in e.g. bioinformatics applications, it seems), then you are better off just iterating over one of the sets and then *constructing* the name of the corresponding files from the other set.

Assuming the files are called `something_R1_more` and `something_R2_more` where `something` and `more` is identifying a particular `R1`-`R2` pair of files.

```bash
for r1 in dir1/*_R1_*; do
    r2=${r1##*/}              # dir1/something_R1_more --> something_R1_more
    r2=dir2/${r2/_R1_/_R2_}   # something_R1_more      --> dir2/something_R2_more

    if [ ! -f "$r2" ]; then
        printf '%s not found\n' "$r2" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    # process "$r1" and "$r2" here
done
```

Comment: Rather than deleting elements from arrays, I'd recommend iterating over the array index(es). E.g. calculate the minimum of `${! dir1names[@]}` and `${! dir2names[@]}`, then use `for ((i=0; i<minlength; i++)); do ... something with ${dir1names[i]} and ${dir2names[i]}; done`

Answer (score 0):

The output of multiple variables can be saved in single variable as mentioned below one. Check if it works for you

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /
for file1 in $(ls /usr/ ; echo "::::::NEXT:::::::" ; ls /sys/)
do
    echo $file1
done
```