# I need to create a loop in bash to join images vertically and ouput multiple joined Pages for print

Tags: bash, for, seq

**I am running Ubuntu 18.04.** I have a directory full of storyboard images in `.jpg` format as below.

```
image-0000.jpg
image-0001.jpg
image-0002.jpg
image-0003.jpg
image-0004.jpg
.
.
image-3898.jpg
image-3899.jpg
```

**Merging 13 images vertically gives me a Single page.** So I think I need to use below command, using a range of 13 numbers at a time in a loop and save to a directory `"./Merged"`.

```
convert -append image-{range of 13}.jpg ./Merged/page_001.jpg
```

> **My experiment and thought process is as below.**

I am trying to use a nested `for` loop and `seq -w` as below. But I am unable understand, how to loop the scrip in such a way that it takes first 13 files `(from image-0000 to image-0012)`, merges them and saves in the `./Merged/` folder. Then come out of the loop and again take the next 13 files `(from image-0013 to image-0025)` and so on. Till all `.jpg` files in the current folder are finished or till 300 pages are generated.

**My Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

# As 3899 image slices will be converted to 300 pages
# I thought to run for loop 300 times

for ((page=1; page<=300; page++))
do
   # As images are slices of pages.
   for slices in $(seq -w 0 3899)
   do

    # We need to merge 13 times so...
    # Should i use for loop with increment as below?
    # for ((smerge=1; smerge<=13; smerge++))
    # do
    #   convert "SOME LOGIC" ./Merged/page_001.jpg
    # done

    # **OR**
    # somehow take 13 numbers from sequence

        convert image-$slices_{RANGE}.jpg -append ./Merged/page_$page.jpg 
        
   done

done
```

Comment: Do you "need" to create a nested loop, or would using [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) solve the problem for you?

Comment: Hello Philip kendall I dont know montage. I think a loop will help. Still i will check montage too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked Montage. it is not for my problem. Still thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

typeset -Z3 page
files=(image-<0-3900>.jpg)
for ((page = 1; $#files; page++)) {
  convert $files[1,13] -append ./Merged/page_$page.jpg
  files[1,13]=()
}
```

Note that since there are 3901 images (13 × 300 + 1), the last page will have only one image.

You can do something similar with `bash` like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s failglob
set -- image-+([[:digit:]]).jpg
for ((page = 1; $#; page++)) {
  printf -v padded_page %03d "$page"
  convert "${@:1:13}" -append "./Merged/page_$padded_page.jpg"
  (($# > 13)) || break
  shift 13
}
```

POSIXly, assuming there are matching files and doing a yet less close check on file names:

```
#! /bin/sh -
set -- image-*.jpg

# disable split+glob, only retain empty removal on unquoted expansions:
set -o noglob; IFS=

page=1; while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  padded_page=000$page
  padded_page=${padded_page#"${padded_page%???}"}
  convert $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 ${10} ${11} ${12} ${13} \
    -append "./Merged/page_$padded_page.jpg"
  [ "$#" -gt 13 ] || break
  shift 13
  page=$((page + 1))
done
```

Note that while here the file names are very tamed (no blanks, special characters...), special care has been taken in those codes to handle arbitrary characters. However note that `convert` and other imagemagick utilities could have problems with file names starting with `-` (even when using `--`) or containing `:`, so best is to  prefix file paths with `./` to avoid those problems (for instance, use `./*.jpg` instead of `*.jpg`).

Comment: **Thank you Stéphane Chazelas.** I was able to solve yesterday morning. Still I would like to check your solution too. Soon I will post my solution too.

Comment: As the file naming starts from 0000 it ends at 3899, Sorry about that i Corrected it.

Comment: is there anything after IFS=

Comment: @user3025253, no. That's the point. We empty `$IFS` (the internal field separator), to disable word splitting.

Comment: zsh script failed with errors
POSIX script is creating only one file "page_001.jpg". Script is working but it is overwriting on to one file.

Comment: @user3025253, what errors?

Comment: **Your 2nd code for bash worked Perfectly**   

_time bash bashChazelas.sh (2 bash)_   

`real 0m7.300s`
`user 0m7.163s`
`sys 0m1.524s`

Comment: @user3025253, about the POSIX one, sorry I had forgotten to  increment `$page`. Should be fixed now.

Comment: This was the error. I copied your script exactly as I dont know zsh. **--->>**   
`line 3: typeset: -Z: invalid option` `line 4: syntax error near unexpected token '<'`  `line 4: files=(image-<0-3899>.jpg)` `line 5: ((: 0files: value too great for base (error token is "0files")`

Comment: **Sorry I was Idiot.** I used bash to execute the script. i will check zsh again.

Comment: @user3025253, those are `bash` error messages, you need to run that script with `zsh`, not `bash`. `zsh ./thescript` or `./the-script` with that `#! /bin/zsh -` shebang and assuming `zsh` is available at that path  and you have made the script executable (like with `chmod +x the-script`).

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have these files in a continuous range from `image-0000.jpg` to `image-2999.jpg`.  This should demonstrate the principle at work here:

```
#!/bin/bash
for page in {000..001}; do
  echo image-${page}{0..9}.jpg
done
```

So, do drop this into your use-case:

```
#!/bin/bash
for page in {000..001}; do
  convert image-${page}{0..9}.jpg --append ./Merged/page-${page}.jpg
done
```

<sub>Note that `{01..02}` expanding to `01` `02` rather than `1` `2` requires `bash` 4.</sub>

Comment: Hi DopeGhoti, Thank you very much. Your solution works with 10 perfectly. But While posting I made a mistake. I need 13 increments. I have corrected my question too. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `xargs` `-n` argument and push the result to a `while` `read` loop.

```
page=1
while IFS= read -r row; do
    convert $row -append ./Merged/page_$page.jpg
    page=$((page + 1))
done < <(echo image-{0000..3900}.jpg | xargs -n13)
```

Comment: **Thank you RoVo.** I was able to solve yesterday morning. Still I would like to check your solution too. Soon I will post my solution too.

Comment: what is this IFS variable? any special system variable? IFS Means?

Comment: This means internal field separator and defines how word splitting is done. In this case not at all because I unset it. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184867

Comment: Your Script worked perfectly and took less time than my solution. almost half the time. `real 0m7.284s`

Comment: But only problem was that I need to keep changing the range, `{0000..3899}` ,  for different situations.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hello everyone. Thank you very much for your time and replies.**
>
> > DopeGhoti, Philip Kendall, Stéphane Chazelas, RoVo

**This is What I was able to create, and it worked.**
Still I would like to check others Solution too. Maybe your solution is faster than my basic Script.

> **NOTE:** This Script will/might fail if there are spaces in file names!

> only script

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: This Script will/might fail if there are spaces in file names!

mkdir -p Finished;
mkdir -p Merged;

for paGe in $(seq -w 1 300)
do
   ls *.jpg | head -n 13 > filesData.txt;
   paGeData=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' filesData.txt);
   convert $paGeData -append ./Merged/Page_$paGe.jpg;

   while read -r line
   do
      mv $line ./Finished/
   done < filesData.txt
done
```

> Script with comments

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: This Script will/might fail if there are spaces in file names!
# I random capitalize letters in a variable to make them unique,
# As i can't be sure.

mkdir -p Finished;
mkdir -p Merged;

for paGe in $(seq -w 1 300)
do
   # Selecting only 13 files from the current directory
   ls *.jpg | head -n 13 > filesData.txt;

   # Replace newline (\n) with space and place "file names"
   # in one line and storing "sed" output to a variable.
   # So that we use it with "convert" command.
   paGeData=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' filesData.txt);

   # Merge different images to one long image
   convert $paGeData -append ./Merged/Page_$paGe.jpg;

   # Move files to different directory,
   # So that we can work with next range/batch of files.
   while read -r line
   do
      mv $line ./Finished/
   done < filesData.txt

done
```

> > **A long thought process. If someone might be interested in how I tried to improvise the code.** This might have some mistakes.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p Finished;
mkdir -p Merged;

for paGe in $(seq -w 1 300)
do

   # Selecting only 13 files from the current directory
   ls *.jpg | head -n 13 > filesData.txt;

   # Replace newline (\n) with space and
   # place file names in one line for the convert command in while loop
#   sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' filesData.txt > paGeData.txt;
   # We can remove below loop by storing sed (above) output to a variable
   # and substituting it later in the command.
   paGeData=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' filesData.txt);

   # Merge different images to one long image
   # "line" is a system variable
#   while read -r line
#   do
#      convert $line -append ./Merged/Page_$paGe.jpg
#   done < paGeData.txt
   convert $paGeData -append ./Merged/Page_$paGe.jpg;

   # Move files to different directory,
   # So that we can work with next range/batch of files.
   while read -r line
   do
      mv $line ./Finished/
   done < filesData.txt

done
```