# How to initialize an array with elements with whitespace from a command output

Tags: bash

The following script:

```
DYN_HOSTS_START_ARRAY=($(grep -E "STARTING HOST" sample.log | cut -d' ' -f 1,2))
for ((i=0; i< ${#DYN_HOSTS_START_ARRAY[@]}; i++))
do
    echo "$i:  start: "${DYN_HOSTS_START_ARRAY[$i]}""
done
```

Using the following sample.log file:

```
2019-11-11 19:05:55,823 DEBUG  STARTING HOST 46
2019-11-11 19:05:55,831 DEBUG  STARTING HOST 703
2019-11-11 19:05:55,837 DEBUG  STARTING HOST 505
2019-11-11 19:05:55,858 DEBUG  STARTING HOST 93
2019-11-11 19:05:55,859 DEBUG  STARTING HOST 486
2019-11-11 19:05:55,861 DEBUG  STARTING HOST 72
2019-11-11 19:05:55,879 DEBUG STARTING HOST 855
2019-11-11 19:05:55,913 DEBUG  STARTING HOST 560
2019-11-11 19:05:56,067 DEBUG STARTING HOST 199
```

Yields the following undesired output:

```
0:  start: 2019-11-11
1:  start: 19:05:55,823
2:  start: 2019-11-11
3:  start: 19:05:55,831
4:  start: 2019-11-11
5:  start: 19:05:55,837
6:  start: 2019-11-11
7:  start: 19:05:55,858
8:  start: 2019-11-11
9:  start: 19:05:55,859
10:  start: 2019-11-11
11:  start: 19:05:55,861
12:  start: 2019-11-11
13:  start: 19:05:55,879
14:  start: 2019-11-11
15:  start: 19:05:55,913
16:  start: 2019-11-11
17:  start: 19:05:56,067
```

The desired output should only have 9 elements (instead of 18), each element containing both the date and the time, separated by the original space.

How do I fix my script, while retaining the array initialization, **to 9 elements only**, to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mapfile -t` and read the your data from a process substitution as [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557936/how-to-initialize-an-array-with-elements-with-whitespace-from-a-command-output/557952?noredirect=1#comment1036701_557952) pointed out.

```
mapfile -t dyn_hosts_start_array < <(grep 'STARTING HOST' sample.log | cut -d' ' -f 1,2)    
for i in "${!dyn_hosts_start_array[@]}"; do
  printf '%s:  start: %s\n' "$i" "${dyn_hosts_start_array[i]}"
done
```

---

Or you could change the `IFS` variable which is used for word splitting to a newline character (default value is space character, tab and newline) and change it back to its original value afterwards.

```
oldifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
dyn_hosts_start_array=( $(grep 'STARTING HOST' sample.log | cut -d' ' -f 1,2) )
IFS=$oldifs    
for i in "${!dyn_hosts_start_array[@]}"; do
  printf '%s:  start: %s\n' "$i" "${dyn_hosts_start_array[i]}"
done
```

---

Output (both variants):

```
0:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,823
1:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,831
2:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,837
3:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,858
4:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,859
5:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,861
6:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,879
7:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,913
8:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:56,067
```

Related:

- [What is the meaning of IFS=$'\n' in bash scripting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting)

Comment: Or use `mapfile -t` from a process substitution.

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed, that's much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print NR-1 ": ", "start:", $1, $2;}' sample.log
```

with the input from the question prints

```
0:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,823
1:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,831
2:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,837
3:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,858
4:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,859
5:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,861
6:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,879
7:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:55,913
8:  start: 2019-11-11 19:05:56,067
```

To have more control over the output formatting you could also use `printf` like this

```
awk '{printf "%d:  start: %s %s\n", NR-1, $1, $2;}' sample.log
```

Command substitution has some pitfalls with whitespace or special characters. Apparently, the two fields from the input are saved in separate array elements. This script combines them based on your original script.

```
DYN_HOSTS_START_ARRAY=($(grep -E "STARTING HOST" sample.log | cut -d' ' -f 1,2))
for ((i=0; i< ((${#DYN_HOSTS_START_ARRAY[@]} / 2)); i++))
do
    echo "$i:  start: ${DYN_HOSTS_START_ARRAY[((2 * $i))]} ${DYN_HOSTS_START_ARRAY[((2 * $i + 1))]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you but that does not initialize any array... ?

Comment: @datsb You did not tell in the question that the contents of the array is important, you only complained about the wrong output. So edit your question (using the `edit` link below the question) and state what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Is there a way to prevent the number of elements in the array from doubling?

Comment: Instead of adding questions in comments, write everything to your question with enough details to allow us to understand what is important for you. If you care about the contents of the array, tell in your question how the array elements should look like.

Comment: Original question re-edited to clarify the 2 requirements. The subject line also clarifies that.