# Exclude directories in locate search

Tags: files, find, directory, locate

A search with `locate` finds paths in the filesystem.
Often, you know a priori you are interested in either files only, or directories only.
A 'locate' search often returns many results. It would be useful to include only one of the types in the result, because it helps shorten the output.

But there is a more interesting argument to leave out either files or directories: because the list of result paths can be ambiguous - not only in theory.

The example below is a real world case, and not unusual:

```
$ locate --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$"
/usr/local/bin/xfce4-keyboard-overlay
/usr/local/share/xfce4-keyboard-overlay
```

Ok, we found something! But... files, or directories?

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/xfce4-keyboard-overlay 
/usr/local/bin/xfce4-keyboard-overlay:   bash script
```

So that is a file...

```
$ file /usr/local/share/xfce4-keyboard-overlay
/usr/local/share/xfce4-keyboard-overlay: directory
```

while the second is not.

This ambiguity is making long lists of paths hard to read, so it would be really nice to filter directories out, for example using a comman line option for `locate`.

Does something like this exist? Even if the filter for directories is separate from locate?

At least, one could use a script to iterate all the file names to check - which may be slow.

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 ${(0)^"$(locate -0 ...)"}(N.)
```

`(0)` is a parameter expansion flag that splits on NUL characters (as we use `locate -0`), short for `(ps:\0:)`.

With `^`, instead of adding `(N.)` at the end of the array, we add it to each element.

`(N.)` is a glob qualifier, `.` to match only regular files, `N` to remove the element if it doesn't match (doesn't exist or is not a regular file, or we can't check). You can also use `^/` instead of `.` to match non-directories instead of only regular files. Or `-.` to determine the type of the file *after symlink resolution* (include symlinks to regular files in the match).

`print -rC1` prints each argument *raw* on `1` `C`olumn (same as `-l` to write one per line, except in the case where there's nothing to print in which case `print -C1` outputs nothing while `print -l` prints one empty line).

You can use any `zsh` glob qualifiers, but note that the *ordering* ones won't have any effect, since we're expanding one glob per file here, so there's only one file to sort for each.

To better identify which files are executable/directory/symlink/socket..., you can also pass the resulting files as arguments to `ls -F` to append some `*/@=`... suffixes

Here assuming GNU tools and a Bourne-like shell:

```
elocate() {
  locate -0e "$@" |
    sort -z |
    xargs -r0 ls --quoting-style=shell --color=always -Fd1U |
    less -FIXR
}
```

Would define a `elocate` function that gives a colorized and paged version of `locate` with file names quoted in shell style to avoid ambiguities, and with suffixes appended to give indications of type.

Answer (score 3):

This is about as inelegant as the other answers, but maybe less inefficient:

```
locate --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$" | 
        while IFS= read -r f; do [ -f "$f" ] && printf "%s\n" "$f"; done
```

(broken into two lines for readability). 
The above will handle names containing spaces. 
The `IFS=` seems to be necessary to handle names with *trailing* spaces,
and, of course, the `-r` lets you handle backslashes.

The “let’s pipe `locate` into something” approach may be doomed to fail
if pathnames containing newlines are present.

---

For more information on `IFS`, read `sh(1)` or `bash(1)`
(by typing `man sh` or `man bash` into a *nix system,
and/or reading it [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash),
[here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash),
[here](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi?q=bash),
and/or [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh)). 
Then read [Understanding IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26784/80216)
and [Bash: read line by line, with IFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4385772/3960947) on Stack Exchange (focus on the answers with more than 5 votes),
and, if you still haven’t had enough,
check out [IFS on Greg’s Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS)
and [IFS search results on the Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/start?do=search&id=ifs) (not on Stack Exchange).

Comment: can you add some info on what the "IFS=" after your `while` statement does?

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: backslashes will still be a problem with many echo implementations. [You should use `printf` for arbitrary data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803).

Comment: there may be a solution to your newlines problem by using "--null" parameter to `locate` and augment your `read` as suggested here http://transnum.blogspot.ie/2008/11/bashs-read-built-in-supports-0-as.html

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
locate --null --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$" |
  xargs -r0 sh -c 'find "$@" -prune ! -type d' sh
```

Comment: Actually, it's even more dirty than it looks... but a good inspitation. Let's pretend it's pseudocode, then it's helpful :)

Comment: @Volker: I agree that it's bad: it will list `/usr/local/share/xfce4-keyboard-overlay` _and every subdirectory thereof_, in your example. Adding `-maxdepth 0` helps.

Comment: It goes even better... :D  `locate --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$" | xargs -I % sh -c "test -d % && echo %"`

Comment: Using `xargs` with `find` was a good idea, I've edited it to make it robust. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` will repeat command for each line if you specify `-L 1` or `-i` parameter.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199266/make-xargs-execute-the-command-once-for-each-line-of-input)

```
$ locate --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$" | xargs -i bash -c '(test -d "{}" && echo "{}")'
```

Admittedly, it is kicking of a new shell for each file, but it does have the benefit of being nice and compact.

**EDIT:** I wasn't quite happy with that answer because it was kicking of a new shell for each file. This should only have two processes:

```
$ locate --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$" | xargs -i echo 'test -d "{}" && echo "{}"' | bash
```

Of course it would be nice if we could avoid kicking of an interpreter altogether, but `xargs` seems to be hamstrung in its ability to chain commands.

Comment: That one just rebooted my machine (there was a file called `/home/evil/$(reboot)/xfce4-keyboard-overlay` and I foolishly ran that as `root`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas +1 for the courage to run "random codez from the internets" as root ;) (scnr)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
while IFS= read i; \
do \
  if [ -f "$i" ]; \
  then \
    echo "$i"; \
  fi; \
done < <(locate --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$")
```

This is more or less the way G-Man did it combined with process substitution.

Comment: Actually, this is more or less the way ***I*** did it, combined with process substitution, minus the ability to handle filenames containing backslashes or having trailing white space. Also, note that the question title says "exclude directories", and this answer *includes* only directories.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
file $(locate -r 'xfce4-keyboard-overlay$') | grep -v directory$ | awk -F: '{ $(NF--)=""; print }'
```

Explanation:

1. `locate ...` finds all files and directories
2. `file $(...)` appends a message at the end of each line with the type of file
3. `grep -v ...` reverse-filters lines containing `directory$`
4. `awk ...` removes what `file ...` appended

Answer (score 0):

gnu `ls` does quite a nice job of classifying nodes on the filesystem:

```
locate <search> | xargs ls -dF | grep -v '/$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one liner:
but you have to repeat your search string.

```
locate search | awk -F"/" '{if ($NF ~ "search") {print $0}}enter code here
```

Or you can put it in a script: mylocate.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
locate $1 | awk -F"/" -vSearch=$1 '{if ($NF ~ Search) {print $0}}'
```

> Usage: sh mylocate.sh "mysearch"

Have a nice day
Thinkerwim.org

Answer (score -1):

What if you combine `locate` with `file` and `grep`?...

```
$ for f in `locate --regex --basename "xfce4-keyboard-overlay$"`; do file $f; done | grep -vi directory
```

Comment: I did not test, but I think that may be slow, because it creates a process for `file` for every single path. Note that there are often many lines of results for locate. My current test is searching for "gnome", giving about 73000 paths to test.

Comment: @Volker: It's worse than that: for every `$f` that is a file, the `file` program will *open* that file and ***read from it***. This is grossly expensive when all you need to do is a `stat()`. … … … … Also, this will give wrong results for files that contain "directory" in their names (such as "phone_directory"). … … … … … (Also, the ``for f in `…`; do …`` syntax cannot handle names containing spaces.)