# Is it safe assume the IFS is set?

Tags: bash

I see following code in a script:

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS='something-special'
# code that needs the special IFS
# ...
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

If the `IFS` is not set before the script fragment then the script sets it to an empty string and the empty `IFS` and undefined `IFS` are different.

The script probably assume the `IFS` is always set. Is it safe to make such assumption?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe to assume that `IFS` is set.

The default value of `IFS` is a string consisting of a space, a tab, and a newline.  This is a requirement of [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03):

> The shell shall set `IFS` to `<space>` `<tab>` `<newline>` when it is invoked.

In a `bash` shell with default settings, `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"` will show the default value of `IFS` as

```
$' \t\n'
```

---

It is *unsafe* to assume that `IFS` has the default value, and it's important to properly quote expansions so that field-splitting does not occur.  It's extra fun to consider what happens if `IFS` contains digits.

See also

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Comment: [An answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264970/70524) on my suggested dupe says otherwise. (Unless you're talking specifically about bash because this is tagged [tag:bash], but then you do mention POSIX, so ...).

Comment: @muru That answer says that `IFS` may possibly not be inherited from the parent environment, in which case it will be set to  space-tab-newline. If is inherited, it may obviously have another value.

Comment: @Inian Added that.