# extract data in bash from url

Tags: bash

How can I extract the ip address and the country and put them individual in a string without any quotes or any other characters which are present in the text by using the next command:

```
info_ip=`wget --tries=1 --timeout=10 -qO- http://ipinfo.io/?callback=callback; echo`
```

$ip = ?

$country = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` to catch the `ip` and `country` and save into an array:

```
IFS=$'\n'
IP_country=( $(awk -F'[:"]' '/ip/ || /country/{ print $5}' <<<"$( wget ... )") )
```

Then first element is `ip` and the next is `country`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${IP_country[0]}"
1.2.3.4
printf '%s\n' "${IP_country[1]}"
IR
```

Or to print all elements:

```
printf '%s\n' "${IP_country[@]}"
1.2.3.4
IR
```

Future reading:

- [Is it a sane approach to "back up" the $IFS variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264926/72456)
- [What is the 'IFS'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16192/72456)