# output redirection when looping over a file to run a command for each line

Tags: shell-script

i'm learning bash on linux, i found script for "while loop reading from a file" and modified a bit as below, i 'm trying to read a list file containing all the git repos, and i wanted to iterate all those git repos and run `git status` for all of them:

```
while read line; 
    do  echo $line;
        cd $line;
        git status;
done < repo.list
```

this part works fine, i can see status of each repo in stdout, but when i tried to write output to another file, it doesn't work:

```
while read line; 
    do  echo $line;
        cd $line;
        git status;
done < repo.list
> status.txt
```

how can i consolidate all `git status` output and write to a file? thanks!

Comment: i'm new to this, can this be done without loop?
i googled a bit and found this `find mydir -name .git -type d` , i write this to repo.list file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i googled a bit and found this find mydir -name .git -type d

You could do something like this, maybe:

```
find . -name '.git' -type d -print -execdir git status \;
```

That would look for directories called `.git`, then for each, print the path to it, and go to the containing directory and run `git status` there. (`find -exec` would run the command in the original directory, `-execdir` goes to where the matching file/directory was.)

You get output like

```
./this-stuff/.git
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

and it would need some more trickery to post-process the `.git` out of it. (E.g. `-exec sh -c 'echo "${1%.git}"' sh {} \;` instead of the `-print`.)

In general, `find` may work if you want to do something on *all* files/directories in some subtree, matching some condition that is evident from the metadata of the files. But if you have an existing list, a shell loop is as good a way as any to process it.

Comment: `-printf '%h\n'` would do the trick with GNU `find`.

Comment: This answer doesn't show how to redirect the output, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @Barmar, You are absolutely correct. The answer says exactly nothing at all about redirections.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, i'm learning new stuff, i didn't know this could be done with 1 line of command, i added `> status.txt`, it output paths and status of all git reps

Answer (score 4):

With the redirection on a new line, it applies to the empty command; to fix this, place it on the `done` line:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; 
    do  echo "$line"
        (cd "$line"; git status)
done < repo.list > status.txt
```

See also [Understanding IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26784/86440) and [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/86440) and the linked questions for information on subtleties affecting `read`.

Using a subshell for the `cd` and `git status` together means that the changing directories won’t affect subsequent iterations of the loop, or even the shell running the `while`.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works for me

Comment: That `cd` looks slightly suspect, would this only work if all the paths in the file are absolute?

Comment: btw, i didn't use IFS, i just change the "done" part, it also works, `done < repo.list > status.txt`

Comment: Good point @ilkkachu, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a simple typo as explained by [Stephen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637509/116858) already.

The task of running `git status` in each directory given by the line in a file could be done using `xargs` as well:

```bsh
xargs -I {} git -C {} status <repo.list >status.txt
```

This calls `git -C {} status` for each line in the file `repo.list`.  The `{}` will be replaced by the line read from the file, and the `-C` option to `git` will make the utility use an alternative directory for the `status` sub-command in place of the current one.

To have the repository path outputted before each call to `git status`, call a `sh -c` script:

```bsh
xargs -I {} sh -c 'printf "REPOSITORY: %s\n" "$1"; git -C "$1" status' sh {} <repo.list >status.txt
```

Inside the `sh -c` script, the repository pathname is given by `"$1"`.