# 'For' loop won’t iterate over list when path given as argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I'm practicing *shell scripts* and am trying to make a simple script that takes a directory as an argument, loops through each file within and prints out its name and size.

```
#!/bin/bash
# A practice shell script to try and display a list of file names
# and their sizes using the output of ls -l and cut.
declare -i index
export index=0
export name=""
export size=0

for file in $1 ; do
   index+=1
   name=`basename $file`
   size=`ls -l $file | cut -d " " -f 5`
   echo "$index: $name, size: $size bytes"
done
```

When I give `./*` as the argument, it does it for one file and that's it. However, if I edit the code above and just put `./*` in place of `$1`, it works and loops through all files in the current directory.

Why won’t it do the same, when `$1` is supposed to equal `./*`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that the shell from which you call the script expands the globbing pattern `./*` *before* it is passed to the script. That means, that if your globbing pattern matches e.g. `file1.txt` to `file4.txt`, calling the script as

```
./my_script.sh ./*
```

will actually be interpreted as

```
./my_script.sh file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

and these will be the arguments that the shell script sees.

For further reading, have a look at [the section on shell expansion order](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) in the Bash Reference manual.

There are two possibilities to overcome the problem:

1. If you are sure that you always want to iterate over all files in a given directory, pass the directory as argument, and iterate over

   ```
   for f in "$1"/*
   do
       # operations on "$f"
   done
   ```
2. Alternative, if you are sure that you will only pass file names to operate on, iterate over the entire argument list, as in

   ```
   for f in "$@"
   do
       # operations on "$f"
   done
   ```

---

If you want to do it by passing a glob pattern into the script - which certainly is an interesting exercise - this is also possible (see comment by @ilkkachu). As mentioned by @fra-san in a comment, the approach has advantages - it can add more flexibility to the script usage, and it circumvents the limitation on shell command-line parameters (cf. "argument list too long"; though RAM will still limit the length of the resulting filename list) - but requires you to be extra careful.

- You can prevent the shell from expanding the glob by enclosing the argument in quotes (single or double), or escaping the glob character with a backslash:

  ```
  ./my_script.sh "./*"
  ./my_script.sh './*'
  ./my_script.sh ./\*
  ```
- Inside the script, you would refer to the positional parameter `$1` *unquoted* so that it actually is interpreted by the shell (something that we often want to avoid).
- Since that "interpretation" not only involves expansion (see above), but also word splitting you need to set the [*input field separator* `IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26784/377345) to the empty string to ensure that no word-splitting occurs.
- The `for` loop would then look like

  ```
  IFS=
  for f in $1
  do
      # Operations on "$f"
  done
  ```

---

#### A few general notes on your script:

- [Always quote shell variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary), in particular when they contain filenames, as otherwise your script will stumble on filenames with spaces or other, even more exotic characters in them - remember, even the newline is an allowed character for filenames (yuck)!
- Parsing the output of `ls` is [highly discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) for similar reasons. If you want to identify attributes of a particular file, the `stat` tool is a better choice. For determining the size of a file, e.g., you could use

  ```
  size=$(stat --printf="%s" "$f")
  ```
- It is [recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/377345) to use the "new" `$( ... )` style for command substitutions rather then the old "backtick-style" `` ` ... ` ``.
- It is a good habit to check your shell scripts with [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone tool in many Linux distributions, to guard against this (and other) possible error sources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of how bash interprets wildcards and arguments.
When there is a wildcard, bash interprets it on time and replaces it with all files matching. And that happends, when you replace $1 with ./* - it takes all files from current directory and cycles through them.

When you have

```
for file in $1 ; do
```

it will take just the first argument. That's not what you want.
If you want to cycle through all files, you need to use:

```
for file in $* ; do
```

(which will take ALL arguments)

Alternatively, you can cycle through them using `shift` - which removes first argument as long as there are other:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    file=$1
    shift
    ...
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that in particular when filenames are involved, it is safer to iterate over `"$@"` (with double-quotes) instead of `$*` because of possible word-splitting (see e.g. alternative 2 I mentioned in my answer).