# Command line file explorer/manager that displays the number of files for each directory

Tags: command-line, files, software-rec

I am looking for a command line file explorer/manager that displays the number of files for each directory.

For example,  [`ncdu`](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) displays the folder sizes:

[image]

I would like to have the same with the number of files.

I am aware of `ls -la` or [`find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23139/16704), however I want to be able to navigate through the folders. (with `ls -la` one has to execute this command for each folder one wishes to analyze, and `cd` in between). Example of folder navigation with `ncdu`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ranger does what you need: it is a command-line [TUI] file explorer/manager and it does display the number of files for each directory

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: It gives the number of files in the status line at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens -- did you read the topic and the OP's question ("a command line file explorer/manager that displays the number of files for each directory")? In any event, I edited my answer.

Comment: @FrançoisTonneau : aha, now I get it ("*merci*" for the edit) ...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult finding a program which meets your needs exactly. You could try hacking into midnight commander. It should be straight forward, adding a new coloumn entry, or replacing a current column. On a sidenote, you could switch to zsh, it allows you to define shortcut keys to command templates