# Reporting number of files in Subdirectories, Bash

Tags: bash

I'm working on a Win10 computer, but I usually work on Gitbash or in the linux subsystem.

I'm trying to get the number of files in all subdirectories of a specified directory.

This is a similar question to [How to report number of files in all subdirectories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23130/how-to-report-number-of-files-in-all-subdirectories?newreg=ec153fd79a074e77a5bac983b0277827) But the difference is that I do not have a constant number of levels on all subdirectories, I have something like:

```
Dir1/sub1
Dir1/sub1/subsub1
Dir1/sub2
Dir1/sub3/subsub3/subsubsub3
```

I tried

```
 shopt -s dotglob; for dir in */; do all=("$dir"/*); echo "$dir: ${#all[@]}"; done
```

playing around with the number of levels to search in (* /,* /* /* and so on)

But I cannot really get what Im looking for, something like:

```
Dir1/sub1: Number of files
Dir1/sub2: Number of files
Dir1/sub3: Number of files
```

Comment: You'd want a report of files in each of the directories `sub1`, `sub1/subsub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`, `sub3/subsub3`, and `subsubsub3`? Or just for `sub1`, `sub2`, and `sub3`? If this second option, should `sub1` and `sub3` count files in their subdirectories too?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob nullglob

topdir='./Dir1'

for subdir in "$topdir"/*/; do
    find "$subdir" -type f -exec echo . \; |
    printf '%s: %d\n' "${subdir%/}" "$( wc -l )"
done
```

This small `bash` script would output a list of pathnames of subdirectories of `$topdir` followed by the number of regular files found (anywhere) under each of those subdirectories.

The script loops over all subdirectories of `$topdir` and for each, it runs the `find` command

```
find "$subdir" -type f -exec echo . \;
```

This outputs a dot on an otherwise empty line for each found regular file under `$subdir`.  We output a dot because these are easy to count (filenames can contain newline characters).

The dots are piped to

```
printf '%s: %d\n' "${subdir%/}" "$( wc -l )"
```

Here, `printf` is used to format the output.  It takes the subdirectory path (with the final slash removed) and the count of files.

The count of files is had from `wc -l` which will count the dots coming over the pipe from `find` (strictly speaking, it does not count the dots but the newlines).  Since `printf` itself is not reading its standard input stream, this is instead consumed by `wc -l`.

Setting the `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options at the start allows us to skip the whole loop if there are no subdirectories under `$topdir` (that's with `nullglob`) and also to include hidden directory names under `$topdir` (that's with `dotglob`).

By changing

```
topdir='./Dir1'
```

into

```
topdir=$1
```

you can get the script to take a directory path as its only command line argument.

You may speed the `find` up radically by changing it into the slightly more complex

```
find "$subdir" -type f -exec sh -c 'for pathname do echo .; done' sh {} +
```

(the rest of the loop should be left as it is). This runs a really small in-line shell script for batches of found files, instead of `echo` for each file.  This would be *much* quicker assuming `echo` is a built-in command in the `sh` shell.  (You may want to change `sh -c` to `bash -c` to be sure of that.)  When `-exec echo . \;` is used, `find` would execute `/bin/echo`, which would be slow to do for each file.

Comment: This is great!  Would there be a reasonable way to sort the results?

Comment: @lowcrawler If you make sure that the data is nul-terminated rather than terminated by newlines and that whatever you're sorting by is at the start of each record, then it should be reasonably easy to sort using any `sort` implementation that can handle nul-terminated fields (like GNU `sort`). The only issue is that Unix filenames may consist of tabs, spaces, and newlines, hence the need to use nul-terminated records.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU utilities:

```
find Dir1 -mindepth 2 -type f -printf '%P\0' |
  awk -F/ -vRS='\0' '{n[$1]++}; END{for (i in n) print i ": " n[i]}'
```

Counting only *regular* files for each of the subdirectories of `Dir1`.

Outputs something like:

```
sub1: 3
sub2: 30
sub3: 13
sub4: 3
sub5: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Gitbash on Windows, but I'll assume that whatever platform you're running this script on, you have these installed:

- `bash` v4.x or higher (macOS users will need to install a more recent version via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) or something)
- GNU `find`--really, any standard Unix `find` will do, just not the MS-DOS/Windows version (which is more like `grep`)

Assuming the above, this script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
# USAGE: count_files <dir> ...

declare -A filecount

# Tell bash to execute the last pipeline element in this shell, not a subshell
shopt -s lastpipe

# Run through all the user-supplied directories at one go
for d in "$@"; do
  find "$d" -type f | while read f; do
    [[ $f =~ ^(${d%%/}/[^/]+)/ ]] && (( filecount["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"]++ ))
  done
done

# REPORT!
for k in "${!filecount[@]}"; do
  echo "$k: ${filecount[$k]}"
done
```

Comment: I should really learn how to use Bash properly, this did the job very nicely, how do I cite you for showing me the script?

Comment: @FaustinoDelgado Just point back to this answer. The permalink can be found by clicking on the "share" link at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Does this work on directories given with absolute pathnames? What about pathnames containing newlines?  It also seems to count the number of files in the given directories, not in their subdirectories, as asked for in the question, but that may just be me not understanding your code.  Care to describe what you're doing?

Comment: @Kusalananda How can you introduce new lines in path names?, I do not have that problem fortunately, yet.

Comment: @FaustinoDelgado `touch $'my\nfile'`

Comment: @Kusalananda My original script didn't handle absolute paths, so I just fixed that. It doesn't handle pathnames with embedded newlines...and I'm OK with that. And you probably misread the original regex that I used to extract the partial path for use as the tally index. Both it and the current version match up to the subdirectory component, not just the main directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda And for full disclosure, I just noticed that I’d accidentally edited out a trailing slash from my regex. Time for bed. :)

Comment: Note that using `(( filecount["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"]++ ))` like that is an arbitrary command injection vulnerability. Try for instance with a subdir called `x$(reboot)`. Write it as `filecount[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=$((${filecount[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]} + 1))` to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
find $DIR -mindepth 2 -type f -exec bash -c 'echo ${0%${0#$1/*/}}' {} $DIR  \; | uniq -c
```

1. The `-mindepth 2` means we look only at files which are descendants of direct subdirectories of `$DIR`.
2. `-type f` looks only at files.
3. `-exec bash -c "..." {} $DIR` executes the string with the arguments `{}` and `$DIR`, where `{}` is substituted with each file name found by `find`.
4. The `echo` part extracts the corresponding direct subdirectory of `$DIR` from a descendent filename. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash for an explanation of what `%` and `#` do. The `0` and `1` correspond to the first and second arguments after the string respectively.
5. `find` will list all descendants of direct subdirectories of `$DIR` in succession, so `uniq -c` will return the total number of descendant files along with the name for each direct subdirectory.

Comment: Won't this show `sub3` and `sub3/subsub3` as two different entries?

Comment: Oh I see now. We need a command to extract direct subdirectories of `${DIR}`.

Comment: I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `bash` version is at least 4.0, actually you were almost there.

You can allow your code to count files recursively with the `globstar` shell option. From `man bash(1)`:

> If set, the pattern `**` used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

If you want to recursively count all files, including subdirectories, that are in your top-level directories:

```
shopt -s dotglob globstar
for dir in */; do
    all=( "$dir"/** )
    printf '%s\n' "$dir: ${#all[@]}"
done
```

As in the code you tried, for each of your top-level directory we are populating an array with the results of pathname expansion and then displaying the number of its elements.
`dotglob` is used to include files whose names start with `.` (hidden files).

If you want to recursively count all files except for subdirectory objects, you can just subtract the count of subdirectories from the count of all files:

```
shopt -s dotglob globstar
for dir in */; do
    all=( "$dir"/** )
    alldir=( "$dir"/**/ )
    printf '%s\n' "$dir: $(( ${#all[@]} - ${#alldir[@]} ))"
done
```

However, here I'm assuming a broad definition of "file", which, [in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_164), may refer to a regular file, character, block or FIFO special file, symbolic link, socket, directory, or whatever specific implementations may add beyond the standard.
To count a specific type of files only (e.g. regular files), it may be easier to resort to a `find`-based solution.
Alternatively you can extend the above code, testing for the file type in a loop:

```
shopt -s dotglob globstar
for dir in */; do
    all=( "$dir"/** )
    count=0
    for file in "${all[@]}"; do
        test -f "$file" && count="$(( "$count" + 1 ))"
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$dir: $count"
done
```

But this less convenient solution will also be significantly slower than the `find`-based alternative (e.g. more than two times slower than the faster one in [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500439/315749), tested on Linux with `bash` 5.0 and `find` 4.6).

Also note that, unlike `find` in its default behavior, pathname expansion with the `globstar` option will follow symbolic links that resolve to files, making all the above snippets include them in the counts as well.
(Initially it used to follow symbolic links that resolve to directories too, but this behavior has been changed in `bash` 4.3).

Finally — to also provide a solution that does not depend on the `globstar` shell option — you can use a recursive function to recursively count all regular files in the top-level subdirectories of the `$1` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

# nullglob is needed to avoid the function being
# invoked on 'dir/*' when * matches nothing
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

function count_files () {
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        # Only count regular files
        [ -f "$file" ] && count="$(( "$count" + 1 ))"
        # Only recurse on directories
        [ -d "$file" ] && count_files "$file"
    done
}

for dir in "$1"/*/; do
    count="0"
    count_files "$dir"
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$dir" "$count"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

This will list all first-level directories and the number of files in each subdirectory (recursively)... sorted by number of files.

Answer (score 0):

ls --indicator-style=file-type -R -A Dir1/* | sed '/^$/d' | sed '/.*[/:]$/d' | wc -l

ls has many options + using powerful sed can everything