# Are two files hardlinked?

Tags: shell, files

How can I tell if two files are hard-linked from the command line? e.g. something link this:

```
$ ls
fileA fileB fileC

$ is-hardlinked fileA fileB
yes

$ is-hardlinked fileA fileC
no
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

On most filesystems¹, a file is uniquely determined by its [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) number, so all you need to check is whether the two files have the same inode number and are on the same filesystem.

Ash, ksh, bash and zsh have a construct that does the check for you: the file equality operator `-ef`.

```
[ fileA -ef fileB ] && ! [ fileA -ef fileC ]
```

For more advanced cases, `ls -i /path/to/file` lists a file's inode number. `df -P /path/to/file` shows what filesystem the file is on (if two files are in the same directory, they're on the same filesystem). If your system has the `stat` command, it can probably show the inode and filesystem numbers (`stat` varies from system to system, check your documentation). If you want a quick glance of hard links inside a directory, try `ls -i | sort` (possibly [piped to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/case-insensitive-search-of-duplicate-file-names/22920#22920)).

¹ 
<sub>All native unix filesystems, and a few others such as NTFS, but possibly not exotic cases like CramFS.</sub>

Comment: And definitely not on anything FAT-based, where it would be detected as a "cross-linked" file.

Comment: Note that `fileA -ef fileB` also returns `0` (success) if `fileA` is a symlink to `fileB`, or vice versa, or they both link to the same file.

Comment: how do you actually run the command you suggested? I tried [ .bashrc -ef .bash/.bashrc ] and variations of this but it didn't really work.

Comment: @CharlieParker `[ .bashrc -ef .bash/.bashrc ]` is correct. Without context, of course, I have no idea why it “didn't really work” — you could be comparing the wrong files, you could be not checking the outcome correctly, you could be using a shell without `-ef`, ...

Comment: the thing I still find confusing is that I am used to giving commands in my terminal with a format like CMD [options] arg1 arg2 ... argN but this one seems to violate that format. I don't even know how to ask my system if it has that command cuz I cant do man CMD. How do you suggest I proceed? Btw, thnx for ur response :)

Comment: @CharlieParker The command is actually `[` and is a synonym of `test`. But `man [` or `man test` will give you the man page of the external command, whereas just about every shell out there has a built-in command with slightly different options, so you need to look this one up in your shell's manual.

Comment: If you want to test this simply on the command line, execute this command: `if [ fileA -ef fileB]; then echo Yes; else echo No; fi`

Answer (score 5):

```
function is-hardlinked() {
    r=yes
    [ "`stat -c '%i' $1`" != "`stat -c '%i' $2`" ] && r=no
    echo $r
}
```

Comment: Note that this can be a false positive if the two files are on different filesystems but happen to have the same inode. You need to test the device number as well (`stat -c %d`). And if you're on Linux (given your `stat` command), your shell has the `[ fileA -ef fileB ]` to do all this directly. Also, your command gratuitously breaks with file names containing whitespace or `\[?*`, or begins with `-`: **always put double quotes around command susbtitutions** (`"$(stat -c %i -- "$1")"`).

Comment: Why would you use a bunch of cumbersome but portable constructs, and then the abjectly non-portable `function` keyword with a function name that (on account of containing a dash) violates POSIX conventions on allowed names?

Comment: You forgot to quote your `$1` and `$2`. You might also want to use the `$()` syntax instead of backticks because the brackets make it clear where the command begins and where it ends and nesting is simpler.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', `[`'s `-ef` checks whether the files are the same *after symlink* resolution, while GNU `stat` by default gets information from the symlink itself, so it's not equivalent. You can't use `[`'s `-ef` to check that two symlink files are hard linked to each other. GNU `find`'s `-samefile` can be used instead or approaches based on various implementations of `stat` (provided you get both device and inode number as you said).

Answer (score 3):

As the first poster suggest, you can write a script based on something like this on Linux:

```
stat -c '%i' fileA fileB fileC
```

Comment: This isn't enough: you'll get the same number for the two files if are on different filesystems but happen to have the same inode. You need to test the device number as well (`stat -c %d`). And if you're on Linux (given your `stat` command), your shell has the `[ fileA -ef fileB ]` to do all this directly.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', `[`'s `-ef` checks whether the files are the same *after symlink* resolution, while GNU `stat` by default gets information from the symlink itself, so it's not equivalent. You can't use `[`'s `-ef` to check that two symlink files are hard linked to each other. GNU `find`'s `-samefile` can be used instead or approaches based on various implementations of `stat` (provided you get both device and inode number as you said).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find(1)` version 4.2.11 or newer you can also use this:

```
if [ yes = "$(find fileA -prune -samefile fileB -printf yes)" ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

If `fileA` is the same file as `fileB` then `find` will print "yes" and the condition becomes true.

In contrast to using the file equality operator `-ef` this will spawn a new process.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this very simply with the built-in bash operator `-ef`:

```
[[ file1 -ef file2 ]] && echo Same
```

If the condition evaluates to true (`file1` and `file2` are the same), then it prints "Same". Otherwise, nothing is output.

Comment: This test will also be true if `file1` is a symbolic link to `file2`, or the other way around. I don't really see a difference between this and the accepted answer (which has the same issue).

Comment: @kusalananda Nope, docs specifically say it compares inode numbers: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: Sure, but it resolves symbolic links first. I suggest you test it.

Answer (score -4):

theres is other solution in the `sh` shell :

```js
#!/bin/sh
file1='readlink $1'
file2='readlink $2'
if [ file1==file2 -o file2==file1 ]
then
echo "the files are linked with strong link"
else
echo "the files are not linked"
fi
```

the `readlink` give us the right to copy the `inode` into a string variable and compare it with other string variable . (two files have a string link have the same `inode`).

Comment: Consider updating your answer with code that is actually working. Note that your code will never call `readlink`, will not expand `$1` nor `$2`, and will treat `file1==file2` as one string, and `file2==file1` as another, and both are always _true_ (as they are non-empty strings).  Additionally, `readlink` deals with _symbolic_ links, not hard links.