# How to find file/directory names that are the same, but with different capitalization/case?

Tags: shell, find, filenames

How can I list the file/directory names in a directory recursively that are the same, but with different capitalization/case? ex.:

INPUT (not the `ls` command, the directories):

```
[user@localhost ~/a] ls -R
.:
b

./b:
ize  Ize

./b/ize:

./b/Ize:
[user@localhost ~/a]
```

OUTPUT:

```
/b/ize
```

Comment: I guess you mean "different case" (not "different font size")?

Comment: Duh, capitalization, I couldn't figure out what he was asking.

Comment: @gasko-peter are you looking for files with similar names because you're trying to identify the *same* file with a different names?

Comment: Very similar question [case-insensitive search of duplicate file-names](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/case-insensitive-search-of-duplicate-file-names)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have GNU `uniq`, you can sort case insensitively (`-i`), and use `-d` to print only duplicate lines:

```
find . | sort -f | uniq -di
```

As @StephaneChazelas mentioned in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85412/22222), this might not do what you expect if you can have duplicate paths that only differ in case (like `a/b/foo` and `A/b/foo`).

Comment: You probably want `sort -f` here. Also note that GNU `uniq` has the same limitation as GNU `tr` as in it doesn't work for matching case of multi-byte characters.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas why do I want `sort -f`? If `uniq` can deal with the case, why would I also need to make `sort` case insensitive? And what do you mean by multi-byte characters? Things like `\n`,`\r` etc? How can they have different cases?

Comment: Try `export LC_ALL=C; printf '%s\n' a A b B | sort | uniq -di`. Some locales sort case-insensitively, some others (like C) don't. `uniq` needs a sorted input, its duplicate lines must be adjacent.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming file names don't contain newline characters, you could do something like:

```
find . | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -d
```

Note that some `tr` implementations like GNU `tr` don't change the case of multi-byte characters.

Also note that the path it reports may not be the paths of any file. For instance, if there's a `./a/b/fOo` and a `./A/b/fOo` file, it will report `./a/b/foo`. If it's not what you want, you may want to refine your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

All of these ideas are bad. Use checksums and be sure the files are the same. Then the task becomes easy.

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + |
sort |
perl -a -nE'push(@{$db{$F[0]}},$F[1]);END{for(keys%db){say"Dupe detected @{@db{$_}}"if scalar@{$db{$_}}>1}}'
```

This will sha1sum every file in the directory and all subdirectorys and output all dupes of that file, if there are any. I made the pipeline multiline for readability.

Comment: The OP is not looking for identical files, he's looking for files with the same name, the contents may differ. Sorry, but it is this idea that is bad :).

Comment: His first example said *different font size*, suffice it to assume he doesn't have an idea of what he wants.

Comment: Suffice it to say that English is not his native language, hardly the OP's fault that. However, the example clearly shows that he is not comparing the files, just looking for files of the same name in a case-insensitive manner. All I'm saying is that you might want to read a question more closely before deciding which ideas are "bad".

Comment: Agreed. This doesn't address the OP's concern. I also find it strange that you labeled an answer _accepted by the OP_ as a bad idea because it's not what the OP wants!