# Find case duplicate files and rm uppercase

Tags: shell-script, terminal, rm, duplicate

I have a number of image files that have duplicates across case (ie file.jpg File.jpg).  I need a script like the following except I want to completely remove all uppercase.  I know that fslint can do this, but I want to do it in terminal because there are so many..

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -z | uniq -diz
```

[case-insensitive search of duplicate file-names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/case-insensitive-search-of-duplicate-file-names)

Comment: You need to be more specific.  For example would `./mydir/myfiLe.jpg` be considered a duplicate of `./otherdir/myfile.jpg`?

Comment: I'm sure somebody would find it useful to do this across different paths, but I'm primarily concerned with files in the same directory because, if I understand correctly, this particular situation poses a challenge for windows/mac in a git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script may do what you want (I have it set to echo what it would do, rather than actually do it, so you can see)

```
#!/bin/bash

# This variable will always be in lower case.  That means that if you do
# l=Hello the result will be $l==hello.
typeset -l l

for f in *
do
  l=$f # Forces to lowercase due to typeset
  if [ "$l" != "$f" -a -e "$l" ]
  then
    echo rm "$f"
  fi
done
```

So, for example:

```
$ ls
FIle.JpG  File.jpg  file.jpg

$ rem_case_dup.sh 
rm FIle.JpG
rm File.jpg
```

Comment: And, if you're not certain the upper case files really are dups, you might add a test that they contain the same data (some variant of `if diff >/dev/null 2>&1` will do it, lots of other choices too).

Comment: (1) This answer would be better if you *explained* how `$l` can be different from `$f` right after you’ve assigned `l=$f`.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.   (2) The use if `-a` (and `-o`) in `[`…`]` expressions is discouraged.  Consider using `if [ "$l" != "$f" ]  &&  [ -e "$l" ]` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think basic `typeset` features needed explaining; they've only been around for 25+ years, so aren't new!  A couple of comments added.  Why is `-a` discouraged?

Comment: This is great.  How can I make it recursive?

Comment: Change the `for` loop to something like `find . -type f | while read -r f` - have the find` statement determine the scope of your checks; the rest of the loop will compare to files in the same directory as the upper case file was found in.